# Content within div is overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please click on `open` and then click on `close`. The close is within `SLIDER` div but when the `width` of slider div is `0` the `close` text still appears.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "320px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "320px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "0px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1
}
#main {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #154760;
}
.slider {
  width: 0;
  height: 669px;
  background: #066;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">
  <div style="width:inherit;display:inline-block"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="closeNav()" style="display:inline-block"> CLOSE</a> 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="openNav()" style="margin-left:50px"> OPEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can fix it using **`overflow: hidden`** on **`.slider`**, but I think you would like something more advanced I made. Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38766009/6313073

Answer (score 3):

**▶ 1<sup>st</sup> Option:**

Try adding **`overflow: hidden`** to **`.slider`** as shown in the following snippet:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "320px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "320px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "0px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1
}

#main {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #154760;
}

.slider {
  width: 0;
  height: 669px;
  background: #066;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">
  <div style="width:inherit;display:inline-block"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="closeNav()" style="display:inline-block"> CLOSE</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div class="header"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="openNav()" style="margin-left:50px"> OPEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**▶ 2<sup>nd</sup> Option:**

Or, instead of using **`overflow: hidden`**, you can try something more clever. In this solution I removed one of the links and made the other one be `open` or `close` based upon if slider is shown.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "320px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "320px";
  document.getElementById("open-close").innerHTML = "CLOSE";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("open-close").innerHTML = "OPEN";
}

var opened = false;

document.getElementById("open-close").onclick = function() {
  opened = !opened;
  return (opened) ? openNav() : closeNav();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1
}

#main {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #154760;
}

.slider {
  width: 0;
  height: 669px;
  background: #066;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider,
#open-close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#open-close {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider"></div>

<div id="main">
  <div class="header">
    <a id = "open-close" href="JavaScript:void()"> OPEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` for `.slider` &
remove `margin-left` on open `a` tag on `inline`

```js
function openNav(){
 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft="320px";
 document.getElementById("slider").style.width="320px";
 }
 function closeNav(){
 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft="0px";
 document.getElementById("slider").style.width="0px";
 }
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#f1f1f1}
#main{margin-left:0px;transition:all 0.5s}
.header{width:100%;min-width:320px;height:60px;background:#154760;}
.slider{overflow: hidden;width:0;height:669px;background:#066;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;transition:all 0.5s;z-index:1000;display:inline-block;}
a{color:#fff}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider" > <div style="width:inherit;display:inline-block"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="closeNav()" style="display:inline-block"> CLOSE</a> </div> </div>
<div id="main"><div class="header"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="openNav()"> OPEN</a></div> </div>
```

Comment: If i add oveflow hidden how i will be able to scroll the content within div bcoz its fixed div i need scrolling content to place menu items...

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `z-index: 1000`. Instead toggle your z-index on `openNav()` and `closeNav()`

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "320px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "320px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.zIndex = "1";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.zIndex = "-1";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1
}
#main {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #154760;
}
.slider {
  width: 0;
  height: 669px;
  background: #066;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">
  <div style="width:inherit;display:inline-block"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" style="display:inline-block">CLOSE</a> 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openNav()">OPEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah! .. Not a good solution here you are just playing with z-index. That's not what i'm looking for. I need solution if width is 0 how the div content can be shown. 

SORRY FOR MY POOR ENGLISH

Answer (score 0):

just add `opacity:0` to `slider` when it's closed and `opacity:1` when it's open.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "320px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.opacity= "1";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width= "320px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.opacity= "0";
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width= "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1
}
#main {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #154760;
}
.slider {
  opacity:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 669px;
  background: #066;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">
  <div style="width:inherit;display:inline-block"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="closeNav()" style="display:inline-block"> CLOSE</a> 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="header"> <a href="JavaScript:void()" onclick="openNav()" style="margin-left:50px"> OPEN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```